# Python equivalent of Mathematica's Sow/Reap

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose in Mathematica I define the following function:

```
f[list_] := Map[Prime[Sow[#]] &, list];
```

which outputs a list of prime numbers, such that if the input list has n at position i, then the output list will contain the nth prime number at position i. For example,

```
In[2]:= f[{1, 3, 4}]

Out[2]= {2, 5, 7}
```

Now, if for some reason (debugging, etc...) I want to check what values are being fed into the `Prime` function. Because of the `Sow` command in the function, I can do

```
In[3] := Reap[f[{1, 3, 4}]]

Out[3] := {{2, 5, 7}, {{1, 3, 4}}}
```

For more details on Sow/Reap, see the [Wolfram Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html). My question is, **is there a natural Python equivalent of Mathematica's Sow and Reap functionality?** In particular, is there a way to do this kind of thing without explicitly returning extra things from the python function you want to do it to, writing a second python function that is almost the same but returns something extra, or using global variables?

Comment: You can't do it with functions (without using global variables).  What you can do is write a class that stores the intermediate results somehow, and then read them later.  There's no builtin facility for this, though.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not totally clear that using a global variable would be wrong here.  If I understand those docs right, the Mathematica sow/reap manipulate a sort of global stack.

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is the right way to think about it. As long as the stack included information about what function each sow was called in, one could model it that way. That is, the variable Sow/Reap manipulate must behaves as if it were local to each function call.

Comment: Does it even need to keep track?  I can't tell from the Mathematica docs what's supposed to happen if you reap from a function that uses `sow` and that function calls another function that also uses `sow`.  Do the values all pile up in one reaped list, or are they nested somehow?

Comment: sow passes results to the nearest enclosing reap[].. multiple sows under one reap result in a list of lists (array) of values.  I don't think this question really demands implementing all that complexity though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with two ways to implement a rudimentary version of something like this, each with its own limitations.  Here's the first version:

```
farm = []

def sower(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kw):
        farm.append([])
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapped

def sow(val):
    farm[-1].append(val)
    return val

def reap(val):
    return val, farm.pop()
```

You can use it like this (based on one of the examples from the Mathematica doc page):

```
>>> @sower
... def someSum():
...     return sum(sow(x**2 + 1) if (x**2 + 1) % 2 == 0 else x**2 + 1 for x in xrange(1, 11))
>>> someSum()
395
>>> reap(someSum())
(395, [2, 10, 26, 50, 82])
```

This has a number of limitations:

1. Any function that wants to use `sow` has to be decorated with the `sower` decorator.  This means you can't use `sow` inside inside inline expressions like list comprehensions the way the Mathematica examples do.  You might be able to hack this by inspecting the call stack, but it could get ugly.
2. Any values that are sown but not reaped get stored in the "farm" forever, so the farm will get bigger and bigger over time.
3. It doesn't have the "tag" abilities shown in the docs, although that wouldn't be too hard to add.

Writing this made me think of a simpler implementation with slightly different tradeoffs:

```
farm = []

def sow(val):
    if farm:
        farm[-1].append(val)
    return val

def reap(expr):
    farm.append([])
    val = expr()
    return val, farm.pop()
```

This one you can use like this, which is somewhat more similar to the Mathematica version:

```
>>> reap(lambda: sum(sow(x**2 + 1) if (x**2 + 1) % 2 == 0 else x**2 + 1 for x in xrange(1, 11)))
(395, [2, 10, 26, 50, 82])
```

This one doesn't require the decorator, and it cleans up reaped values, but it takes a no-argument function as its argument, which requires you to wrap your sowing expression in a function (here done with `lambda`).  Also, this means that all sown values in any function called by the reaped expression will be inserted into the same list, which could result in weird ordering; I can't tell from the Mathematica docs if that's what Mathematica does or what.

Comment: The second item of the output should be at least a list of lists (or a tuple of tuples), since in Mma, `Reap[Sow[1, y]; Sow[2, x]; Sow[3, y];]` returns `{Null, {{1, 3}, {2}}}` and `Reap[Sow[1, y]; Sow[2, {x, y}]; Sow[3, {}]]` gives `{3, {{1, 2}, {2}}}`.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no simple or idiomatic equivalent in Python of "sow" and "reap". However, you might be able to fake it using a combination of generators and decorators like so:

```
def sow(func):
    class wrapper(object):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            output = list(func(*args, **kwargs))
            return output[-1]

        def reap(self, *args, **kwargs):
            output = list(func(*args, **kwargs))
            final = output[-1]
            intermediate = output[0:-1]
            return [final, intermediate]

    return wrapper()

@sow    
def f(seq, mul):
    yield seq
    yield mul
    yield [a * mul for a in seq]

print f([1, 2, 3], 4)         # [4, 8, 12]
print f.reap([1, 2, 3], 4)    # [[4, 8, 12], [[1, 2, 3], 4]]
```

However, compared to Mathematica, this method has a few limitations. First, the function has to be rewritten so it uses `yield` instead of return, turning it into a generator. The last value to be yielded would then be the final output.

It also doesn't have the same "exception"-like property that the docs describe. The decorator `@sow` is simply returning a class which fakes looking like a function, and adds an extra parameter `reap`.

---

An alternate solution might be to try using [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy). Since it directly manipulates the AST and bytecode of Python, you may be able to hack together direct support for something more in line with what you're looking for. The [tracing](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing) macro looks vaguely similar in intent to what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Disappointing that there isn't a simple, natural way to do this, but I'm very interested in the reference you provide to macropy. The trace functionality is indeed along the lines of what I want, although I suspect it will generate lots of extra information in the cases I would use it.

Comment: This would be awkward for something like the Mathematica examples that sow one value for each run through an iteration (e.g., `sum(sow(x**2) for x in seq)`).  Your computation function would have to `yield` each value from the iteration while accumulating them into lists that are then somehow re-used to do the actual computation.